# FreeRTOS on STM32F103C8T6 minimal board?

Tags: stm32, freertos

Has anyone got FreeRTOS running on STM32F103C8T6 minimal board.

Is it possible? If it is, any pointers would be great.

Answer (score 1):

I have a same board with me, and few days ago I have successfully ran a Hello World  program with FreeRTOS. Also uploaded same to github. Please find the github link [here](https://github.com/sbodd/bluepill).

The program is very simple and it creates two task with the same priority level. The messages can be seen through UART2 pins (PA2 & PA3). Use any arm cross toolchain to compile the source.

Answer (score -1):

As noted here: http://www.freertos.org/a00090.html#ST - the FreeRTOS demos can be adapted to any part in the family that has enough Flash and RAM - which the part you reference does.  In fact, FreeRTOS will run on any Cortex-M part from any manufacturer that [has enough memory](http://www.freertos.org/FAQMem.html).  That is because the RTOS does not use anything outside of the Cortex-M core itslef, and the core is the same in every device family from every manufacturer.